# Site Contents: Hide add-in link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-contents

Lists can be hidden from view in Site Contents by setting "Hide from browser" using SPD:

[image: Hide from browser screen cap]

Can the same be done for add-in apps somehow? For example, I would like to remove the Nintex Forms add-in link from Site Contents:

[image: Site contents screen cap]

Anyone know if this is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to hide Add-ins from users you can check this link : [Learn why add-ins cannot be hidden from users](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint#CannotBeHidden)

Comment: Well, so much for that ... :( 

Thanks for the info.